# Concern vs consideration

Tags: nouns

> Second consideration was for the maximum size.
>   Second concern was for the maximum size.

Which usage is correct?

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Please check a good dictionary for meaning and usage. Let us know what you found. Good Luck.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

In this case, the first (consideration) will be correct.

Comment: Do you have an explanation for this usage?

Comment: If I got you correctly, there's a talk about choosing something (sizes, eh?). So the "second consideration was for the maximum size" is correct if it means like it was the second thought for the coice.